# unexpected "Visit tags table (default TAGS)" prompt when looking up definitions with lsp-mode and gopls

Tags: company-mode, lsp-mode, lsp, golang, tags

I'm using **company-mode** with **lsp-mode** as lsp client and **gopls** as lsp backend in order to lookup function and variable definitions in go projects.

On some repositories, when I want to lookup a definition (`M-.`) I get an unexpected:

```
 "Visit tags table (default TAGS):..."
```

...instead of jumping to the function definition.

For instance:
[image]

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: What command is `M-.` bound to? `C-h k M-.` will tell you.

Comment: @db48x Here it is: 

M-. runs the command xref-find-definitions (found in global-map),
which is an autoloaded interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘xref.el’.

It is bound to M-., <menu-bar> <edit> <goto> <xref-find-def>.

(xref-find-definitions IDENTIFIER)

  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 25.1.

Find the definition of the identifier at point.
With prefix argument or when there’s no identifier at point,
prompt for it.

Comment: I found the key binding online when installing lsp-mode and it was of course way more practical than typing `M-x lsp-find-definition`, which in this case yields a similar error:
"The connected server does not support method testDocument/definition.
To find out what capabilities support your server use `M-x lsp-describe-session` and exand the capabilities section."

Comment: The result of `M-x lsp-describe-session` is in here: https://pastebin.com/4d30E6Gw
I do not know how to interpret it...

Comment: Ok, `xref-find-definition` is the default binding for that key. From your description of the problem it sounds like sometimes the keybinding isn’t getting changed to something related to lsp or company mode. Given your second comment, I suspect that this happens when the lsp server doesn’t support the `testDocument/definition` method.

Comment: My fault for the typo above, it was: `textDocument/definition`
Anyway, the same problem appears in vscode it seems and their solution is to just open the IDE on a the project root folder instead of  on a specific source file, and it works with emacs too!

Ok, so I went past this issue. Thanks! However, I still see a related error: say that I lookup a definition that appears in a different source file, then I look around in that second source file and lookup more definitions; at this point, it will just stall for a a few seconds and then will time out:

Comment: "Timeout while waiting for response. Method: textDocument/references"

Comment: The source for the solution I mentioned above is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49977881/497180

Comment: Sounds like a problem with how the LSP server is started. You should post that as an answer to your own question, but you might also look into changing how `lsp-mode` starts the lsp server; perhaps it could determine the correct directory to start it in automatically. Or perhaps setting `lsp-auto-guess-root` would work: https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/settings/mode/#lsp-auto-guess-root

Comment: As for my remaining problem (`lsp-find-definition` fails with `timeout while waiting for response. Method: textDocument/definition`), I see that it happens (mostly? uniquely?)  in the kubernetes repository I (re-)cloned recently. I don't see it in other repos. Can I make gopls rescan this repo, so to speak? `lsp-workspace-restart` didn't fix it...

Comment: One question at a time; you should start a new one for that.

Comment: Sure! https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68740/emacs-stalling-when-looking-up-definitions-with-lsp-mode-and-gopls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, a workaround for this issue is to start emacs on a folder (or on nothing) instead of on a single source file.
This was discussed for VScode with gopls as backend here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49977881/497180