# emacs stalling when looking up definitions with lsp-mode and gopls

Tags: company-mode, lsp-mode, lsp, golang, tags

I'm using lsp-mode as lsp client and gopls as lsp backend in order to lookup function and variable definitions in go projects.

On a given large repository (kubernetes) that I recently wiped and cloned again, I see that, when I want to lookup a definition (`lsp-find-definition`), emacs will stall for a few seconds and then fail:

```
"Timeout while waiting for response. Method: textDocument/references" –
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Notice that all the definition lookups worked fine before I deleted the project folder and re-crated it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround for this is to disable file watchers:

```
(setq lsp-enable-file-watchers nil)
```

... and then restart the workspace:

```
(lsp-restart-workspace)
```

I'm not sure if this effectively disables a useful feature, but I can't get it to work otherwise.

The solution was described here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/38032

More about file watchers here: https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/file-watchers/

Answer (score 1):

You can lengthen the timeout using the `lsp-response-timeout` option: https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/settings/mode/#lsp-response-timeout

Of course, what you really want to do is make gopls faster. Probably not much you can configure in Emacs to do that.

Comment: AFACIT setting the `lsp-response-timeout` to a different value also required restarting the workspace with M-x `lsp-restart-workspace`.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem too, and it did timeout each time as I saved file. I configured the `lsp-format-buffer` and `lsp-organize-imports` as the hook of `before-save-hook`.

When I dived into the Emacs `*lsp-log*` buffer (you can also invoke `lsp-describe-session`), I found that Emacs used my `$HOME` as the root of current `lsp-workspace-folder` instead of the current project path, so it timeouted, and it made sense.

So what I did is to invoke `lsp-workspace-folders-remove` and remove the `$HOME` folder and re-visit my project, and select current folder as the root. It worked!

For more configuration, you can access my Emacs dot file https://github.com/yuanbohan/dot-files/blob/master/emacs/conf/conf.org#go